# How to display the empty cells before fetching the data in angular7 from json file into the table?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I need to display the table with empty cells and when i click on calculate i need to get the data from json file.

**inputselection.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from "src/app/earlysizing/data.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inputselection',
  templateUrl: './inputselection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inputselection.component.scss']
})
export class InputselectionComponent implements OnInit {

  messageForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  success = false;
  public closestbenchmarks = [];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _emp: DataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCalculate() {
  this.submitted = true;
    if (this.messageForm.invalid) {
     return;
    }
    this._emp.getClosestBenchMarks().subscribe(data => 
      {
        this.closestbenchmarks = data;
        console.log('DATA', data);
      }); 
   //alert("SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n" + JSON.stringify(this.messageForm.value));
    this.success = true;
  //console.log("Valid");
  }
}
```

**inputselection.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th rowspan="2"></th>
       <th class="text-center" colspan="5" >Closest Benchmarks</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">First Closest</th>
          <th scope="col">Second Closest</th>
          <th scope="col">Third Closest</th>
          <th scope="col">Fourth Closest</th>
          <th scope="col">Fifth Closest</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let c of closestbenchmarks">
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">Name</td>
        <td>{{c.name.firstClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.name.secondClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.name.thirdClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.name.fourthClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.name.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">Global Reporting Brand</td>
        <td>{{c.globalReportingBrand.firstClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.globalReportingBrand.secondClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.globalReportingBrand.thirdClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.globalReportingBrand.fourthClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.globalReportingBrand.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">Launch Timing</td>
        <td>{{c.launchTiming.firstClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.launchTiming.secondClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.launchTiming.thirdClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.launchTiming.fourthClosest}}</td>
        <td>{{c.launchTiming.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Country</td>
          <td>{{c.country.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.country.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.country.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.country.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.country.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Segment</td>
          <td>{{c.segment.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.segment.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.segment.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.segment.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.segment.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Distribution Level</td>
          <td>{{c.distributionLevel.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.distributionLevel.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.distributionLevel.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.distributionLevel.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.distributionLevel.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Serving</td>
          <td>{{c.serving.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.serving.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.serving.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.serving.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.serving.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Flavour(s)</td>
          <td>{{c.flavour.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.flavour.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.flavour.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.flavour.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.flavour.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Package Type</td>
          <td>{{c.packageType.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packageType.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packageType.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packageType.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packageType.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Price Tier</td>
          <td>{{c.priceTier.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.priceTier.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.priceTier.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.priceTier.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.priceTier.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Carbonated?</td>
          <td>{{c.carbonated.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.carbonated.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.carbonated.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.carbonated.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.carbonated.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Pack Size(S)</td>
          <td>{{c.packSize.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packSize.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packSize.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packSize.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.packSize.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Volume % Share vs. Segment</td>
          <td>{{c.volumeShareKgVsSegment.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.volumeShareKgVsSegment.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.volumeShareKgVsSegment.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.volumeShareKgVsSegment.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.volumeShareKgVsSegment.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Value % Share (USD) vs. Segment</td>
          <td>{{c.valueShareUSDVsSegment.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.valueShareUSDVsSegment.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.valueShareUSDVsSegment.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.valueShareUSDVsSegment.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.valueShareUSDVsSegment.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Launch Year Volume Sales (MM)</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearVolumeSales.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearVolumeSales.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearVolumeSales.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearVolumeSales.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearVolumeSales.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td scope="row">Launch Year Value Sales ($MM USD)</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearValueSales.firstClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearValueSales.secondClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearValueSales.thirdClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearValueSales.fourthClosest}}</td>
          <td>{{c.launchYearValueSales.fifthClosest}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button type="button" class="button btn-lg">Calculate</button>
```

I need to display the table with empty cells onloading and when i click on calculate i need to get the json data.

Before: 
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9pLc.png)

After: 
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLA1k.png)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to set default value for **closestbenchmarks** field with empty strings:

```
public closestbenchmarks = [
{
   name: { firstClosest: "", secondClosest: "", thirdClosest: "", ...},
   globalReportingBrand: { firstClosest: "", secondClosest: "", thirdClosest: "", ...},
   launchTiming: { firstClosest: "", secondClosest: "", thirdClosest: "", ...},
   ... 
}
...
];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks So much  Amir Arbabian

Comment: No problem, i'm glad that it helped!